# keeping my hero section in the same position across all devices

Tags: html, css

I have finished a website more or less. I am trying to keep the hero section of my website consitent in the middle. my problem comes when I upload my website into github and test it on a galaxy a13 5g the hero section does not appear in the same position as I look at it when i shrink my browser.

I tried adding and subtracting margin, the problem is that when I add more margin the hero section disappears or the call to action button is not visable and when I subtract margin the hero section not in the center when I shrink my browser. here is my code.
ps I am using this image[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PjJQe.jpg)
ps the hero section should be to the left side of the image.

```
@media only screen and (min-width:300px) {
main .landing-page .hero-section {
display: flex;
max-width: 300px;
flex-direction: column;
align-items: flex-start;
gap: 10px;
margin: 120px 10px;
animation: slideIn 0.9s ease forwards;
position: relative;
left: -300px;
opacity: 0;
}
}
```

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 700px) {
    main .landing-page .hero-section {
        max-width: 500px;
        margin: 50px 10px;
        }
}
```

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
    main .landing-page .hero-section {
        max-width: 500px;
        margin: 120px 10px;
        }

}
```

Comment: Can you update the code in the question to a [runnable code snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/328193) as a [mcve] which demonstrates the problem?